# How do I change the Template Layout for the Customer 'My Account' page?

Tags: layout, template, ce-1.9.0.1, custom

This might be very basic...

I need to change the Template Layout for the "My Account" page

It is currently using:
frontend/mypackage/mytheme/template/page/2columns-left.phtml

And I need to change it to:
frontend/mypackage/mytheme/template/page/1column.phtml

I can't see any way to change it... I don't even know which file the template is defined. It *might* be using the 'default' setting - but I don't know where that is populated. Please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using a theme. It might have it's own XML to define layouts or not, since i dont know the theme i cant tell you. But the most normal way to do this is to open customer.xml in the layout folder of your theme and  find the path to the My account page (customer_account_index) and change your layout from there.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890332/magento-set-customer-my-account-layout-to-one-column), it is very similar to your question and might help you.

Comment: It's *exactly* what I was looking for :) Thank you!